# How to handle promises for mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose i just want to understand once we have data from client how to save and hanlde promises using nodejs with mongoose schema. In below example trying  to save the data to collection handle promises if any error occurs.

model.js

```
var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

var UserAccessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  uid: String,
  email: String,
});

export default mongoose.model('UserAccess', UserAccessSchema);
```

controller.js

```
var UserAccess = require('./access.model');

export function create(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  UserAccess.createAsync(req.body)
    .then()
    .catch();

}
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./access.controller');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', controller.create);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Promise.promisifyAll the object you want to access the async objects.

Such as this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserAccessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  uid: String,
  email: String,
});

var model = mongoose.model('UserAccess', UserAccessSchema);

model = Promise.promisifyAll(model)

export default model;
```

This way, you will have your model with the appropriate `async` methods created.

But, just to be clear, you do not need bluebird to work with Promises with bluebird.

You can actually just append the method after queries `.exec()` to return a Promise.

You can refer to the [section](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think you need `.exec()` . I do stuff like `Model.find().then(function(docs){})`

Comment: @jackblank The query is thenable, but it doesn't mean it's a promise. For example, you don't have the catch method.